# Can't read superblock on RAID 10 LUKS array after rsync freeze (Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 with Budgie desktop)

Tags: luks, superblock

During an rsync from an external LUKS raid 10 array (connected by e-sata) to an internal drive, the OS froze.

After rebooting, I can no longer access the external raid 10. When I click on it I get the following error message:

```
Error mounting filesystem
Error mounting /dev/dm-0 at /media/marco/EXT_RAID_10: can't read superblock
on /dev/mapper/luks-49aa238c-96bc-4bf6-abeb-1f4b018ccabe (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

The system is Ubuntu server 18.04.3 with Budgie desktop. All 4 drive lights are on indicating they are supposedly fine

Output from sudo fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x373d828f

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda2            2048 468860927 468858880 223.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       443695104 468860927  25165824    12G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6            4096 226996223 226992128 108.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       226998272 443693055 216694784 103.3G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdf: 3.7 TiB, 4000694927360 bytes, 7813857280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B9829E9E-44BE-4381-BB42-387062B5252D

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdf1   2048 7813855231 7813853184  3.7T unknown


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-49aa238c-96bc-4bf6-abeb-1f4b018ccabe: 3.7 TiB, 4000690733056 bytes, 7813849088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Output from sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdf1:

```
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdf1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

/dev/sdf1 contains a crypto_LUKS filesystem
```

Output from sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdf1:

```
Creating filesystem with 976731648 4k blocks and 244187136 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 11a09e27-4114-4555-8dd3-afcf61deacc4
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544
```

Output from sudo e2fsck -b 98304 /dev/sdf1:

```
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdf1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

/dev/sdf1 contains a crypto_LUKS filesystem
```

In the end the problem was simply the drive was locked because of the interrupted rsync command (also happened when I interrupted a simple cp command). This simple lockdown was made complicated by the LUKS encryption giving the cryptic (pun intended) error message. I solved this by removing the lock following the instructions on:
https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/how-to-recover-a-luks-encrypted-disk/

In short:

```
1. Boot from a recovery disk

2. Determine /dev address of locked LUKS partition (in this case /dev/sdh1):
~$ sudo fdisk -l

3. Display LUKS header info:
~$ sudo cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/sdh1

4. Unlock partition with LUKS passphrase:
~$ sudo cryptsetup -v luksOpen /dev/sdh1 sdh1_crypt

5. Mount drive using Nautilus or manually:
~$ mkdir /tmp/disk
~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/sdh1_crypt /tmp/disk
```

Comment: After the crash/freeze did fsck run?, also this is a 64-bit system? Make sure your tools are also 64-bit...

Comment: You might want to try this page also __Data Recovery__ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Yes it is 64-bit: Intel i7-3770k. Ubuntu is 64-bit and the tools above were installed from standard repositories

Comment: Well I tried the "Check filesystem" tool in gnome-disks and somehow the error message changed after this to: "Structure needs cleaning"...

So I tried the "Repair filesystem" from gnome-disks and got this message:

Error repairing filesystem on /dev/dm-0: Process reported exit code 12: e2fsk 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)

Comment: You may want to try TestDisk before throwing it away: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Advanced_FAT_Repair " A Linux mount will display wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the cable and did this:
https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/how-to-recover-a-luks-encrypted-disk/

Worked for me:

```
1. Boot from a recovery disk

2. Determine /dev address of locked LUKS partition (in this case /dev/sdh1):
~$ sudo fdisk -l

3. Display LUKS header info:
~$ sudo cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/sdh1

4. Unlock partition with LUKS passphrase:
~$ sudo cryptsetup -v luksOpen /dev/sdh1 sdh1_crypt

5. Mount drive using Nautilus or manually:
~$ mkdir /tmp/disk
~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/sdh1_crypt /tmp/disk
```

Comment: You should mark your answer as Answered with a green checkmark so we all know you have solved your machine's problem. It may help others. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a Raid setup however, I have run into errors with Linux myself.

Make sure it is not your cables eSATA.

> [**How To Repair a File System Error on Ubuntu**](https://ccm.net/faq/3505-repair-file-system-errors-on-ubuntu)
>
> **Boot your system using the Ubuntu installation CD**, and then select Test Ubuntu.
>   
> Next, open a terminal, and use the command line
>   
>    *$ sudo fsck.ext3 -f /dev/sdaX*
>   
> to launch a search for any errors. All errors found should be repaired.
>   
>   
> You can ask the system to check the file system at the next 
>   reboot by typing
>   
>    *sudo touch /forcefsck*